# Android Studio and PhoneGap, Module android is not backed by gradle

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-studio

A while back I've worked with Eclipse and Phonegap and I've successfully deployed a few Android apps. So now I'm trying to get the new Phonegap/Cordova app up and running in Android Studio but so far without any luck. Here's what I've tried:

1) I've generated a cordova app and added android as platform.

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello
cordova platform add android
cordova -version
```

[image]Ok this works

2) Then I start Android Studio and import the generated app and a message "Gradle settings for this project are not configured yet" appears and I press OK.
[image]

3) Then I get an error "Gradle version 1.10 is required. current version is 2.2.1" and after some googling I found [a hint here](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/473) and I changed a line in Gradle from `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'` to `:0.14.+'` and now the RUN icon at the top is enabled so it seems to have fixed at least something. Although the version nr doesn't make sense to me but from what I can gather the versions are very specific.

But now I'm stuck on the error "Module android is not backed by gradle" and I don't know what to do.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: right now android studio isn't supported by cordova apps, cordova 3.7 will be released soon and I think it will bring the support

Comment: Cordova js 3.7 was released last november (see link below), and I'm using Cordova-CLI v4.2.0, see first screenshot. So I don't know exactly what you mean with v3.7.

http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/11/06/cordova-ios-3.7.0.html

Comment: Sorry, I meant cordova android (latest version is 3.6.4), now each platform has it's own version. http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/01/09/tools-release.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Okay I've figured it out so I'll just answer my own question. Hopefully it will also benefit someone else trying to do the same thing.

There are actually **two build.gradle files**, one in the main project and one in the CordovaLib folder. I guess CordovaLib is a subproject within the main project. So after generating the Cordova project and importing it into Android Studio an error appears

```
Error:Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.2.1.
```

Edit the build.gradle files and make the following change in both files:
change `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'`
to this : `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'`
Btw I know the error message said v1.10 but changing it to that gives another error "Could not find.." and "1.0.0" seems to work, so yeah go figure...

Then I select Build -> Rebuild Project from the menu and it gives another error

```
Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.0) is too low for project 'android'.
Minimum required is 19.1.0
```

Clicking on the error message unhelpfully does nothing, but I again edit the build.gradle files and change `buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"` to `buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"` in both files. To sum up the changes see screenshot below:

[image]

Then again select `Build -> Rebuild Project` from the menu, and it will give an error in the Gradle Console

```
Error: Task '' not found in root project 'android'.
```

Just ignore it, and do `Build -> Rebuild Project` again and then it will give an info dialog "Language level changes will take effect on project reload. Would you like to reload project "android" now?" and press Yes.

The project will reload and is now ready to run on a device or in the emulator. :) phew..

Comment: Thanks a ton!  The 1.0.0 instead of 1.10 was what did it for me.

Comment: Did you happen to start getting any issues like this after doing the above? 
`Error:Unable to load class 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.ShortTypeHandling'.`

Comment: Nope, I don't know but that looks like a separate groovy-related issue.

Answer (score 1):

From [this link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_tools.md.html#Android%20Shell%20Tool%20Guide)

Cordova for Android now supports building with Gradle.

To build `cordova` with `gradle`

1. Right click on `My computer` -> `properties` -> `Advanced system setting` -> `Environment Variables` and create **ANDROID_BUILD** system variable with value **gradle**
2. Now `cordova build android` will create gradle project which can be easily imported as a android studio project.

**Note :**

If you are behind proxy then you have to set proxy first with

```
 gradlew -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.blah.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8000
```

**gradlew batch file**  will be created automatically in your directory