# Cordova doesn't work

Tags: android, cordova

I'm reading the book ***"Beginning NFC Near Field Communication with Arduino, Android, and PhoneGap"***. On page 29 under ***"Creating a PhoneGap Project"*** I'm trying to create a PhoneGap project with this command `cordova create ~/Hello com.example.hello Hello` and `cordova platform add android`. Everything seems (at least to me) to go well until when I try to run `cordova run` which spits the following lines:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/moki/Work/Tools/android-sdk-linux/
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91
No target specified, deploying to device 'CB5A2AKNFT'.
Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:675)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1536)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    ... 3 more
Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/moki/Work/src/Hello/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/moki/Work/src/Hello/platforms/android/build.gradle,-PcdvBuildArch=arm,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

I'm unable to figure out what's the problem. How can I fix that?

I've installed `Android SDK tools rev 25.1.3`, `Android SDK Platform-tools rev 23.1`, `Android SDK Build-tools rev 23.0.3` and `Android 6.0 (API 23) SDK Platform`. What else do I have to do to be able to run my first project successfully?

I'm trying to work under `Debian Jessie`  OS. I'v also set my Android phone which is a Sony Xperia Z5 dual premium and it's already in developer mode with usb debugging enabled.

Comment: Do you do a "cordova build android" cli? Also, based on my experience, try to launch it thru Android Studio, if there is an issue with the graddle file it tells you what and you'll be able to fix it.

Comment: @nyluje No the book didn't mention this step. Do I have to execute that command within my `Hello` folder? I tried to execute it within my project's folder but that also failed with  `Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/moki/Work/Tools/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 127`

Comment: After you do the "add platform android". Maybe it is not in your Arduino doc, but have a look at the Cordova one.

Comment: I had similar problem in the past, you should investigate that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056398/android-studio-and-phonegap-module-android-is-not-backed-by-gradle

Comment: @nyluje thanks! your suggestion of running `cordova build android` fixed the issue. Please write it as an answer so I can accept it and let you have your well-deserved reputation points.

Comment: the answer is there;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run "cordova build android" in CLI after you've entered "cordova add platform android".

Have fun!